# Como encontrar facturas por id de cliente

Tags: nodejs, mongoose

no logro entender cómo encontrar facturas por id de cliente. Yo lo razone así. Este es mi código:

Esquema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const facturaEsquema = new Schema({

numero: Number,

fecha: {type: Date, default: Date.now()},

tipo: String,

sucursal: String,
cliente: {
type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
ref: 'clientes'
},

detalle: [{
    cantidad: Number,

    producto: {codigo: Number,
               nombre: String,
               precio: Number
    },
    subtotal: Number
}
],
total: Number

});

mongoose.model('facturas', facturaEsquema);
```

Y este es mi metodo post:

```
 app.get('/api/facturas/cliente/:id', (req, res) => {
    console.info('Obteniendo cliente de factura');
    try{
      const id = req.body.cliente._id;
    const cliente = Factura.findById(id)
    .populate("cliente","direccion nombre email cuil telefono -_id");

    if (cliente) {
      res.send(cliente);
  } else {
      res.status(404).send({ message: `El cliente con id: '${id}' no ha 
podido ser encontrado. ` });
  }
  } catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
  res.status(500).send({ message: `Error en el servidor.\n\n${err}` });
  }

      });
```

Lo que quiero tratar es encontrar las facturas por id de cliente. Todas las facturas con cliente que tiene un id.

¿Pero cómo las encuentro?

Me dice lo siguiente:

"message": "Error en el servidor.\n\nTypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined"

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sustituye:

```
 const id = req.body.cliente._id;
```

por

```
 const id = req.params.id;
```

Las rutas get no tienen body, y el id del cliente se lo estas pasando por parametro en la url

Comment: Sí, está bien lo que Ud. dice. Puede Ud. creer que lo hice asi y no funcionó?, sustituí como Ud. dijo recién y cambié la función findById por findOne y ahí funcionó.